# my checkAll Checkboxes script not work

Tags: jquery

I Am using jquery 1.6.1 for checking all a group of checkboxes.
this is my HTML Code:

```
 <form action="">
    <div class="stats">
      <h2 class="title">Reason for Celebrity</h2>
      <input name="reason" type="checkbox" value="net" />Famous on the internet<br/>
      <input name="reason" type="checkbox" value="crim" />Committed a crime<br />
      <input name="reason" type="checkbox" value="model" />Dates a super model<br />
      <input name="reason" type="checkbox" value="tv" />Hosts a TV show<br />
      <input name="reason" type="checkbox" value="japan" />Big in Japan<br />
      <hr />
      <input class="check-all" name="reason" type="checkbox" /><span>Check all</span>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

and my script for check all is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.check-all:checkbox').change(function() {
    var group = ':checkbox[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']';
    $(group).attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
  });
});
```

but this not work on uncheck of checkboxes. can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace

```
$(group).attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
```

with

```
$(group).attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr('checked')` - returns undefined

You should do this:

```
var variable = (undefined == $(this).attr('checked'))?false:$(this).attr('checked');
$(group).attr('checked', variable);
```

To avoid the undefined value

Comment: thanks. but why $(this).attr('checked') return **false** in unchecking check-all checkbox

Comment: Because the the possible values are true, false and 'checked' as far as I know. true and 'checked' have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you did not add any option explicitly to uncheck the checkboxes.
One proper way to do this would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.check-all:checkbox').change(function(event) {
    var group = ':checkbox[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']';
      $(group).each(function(){
      this.checked = event.target.checked;
      });
  });
});
```

A working fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/PmuLz/2/